# What's the difference between retail symbols and checked symbols?

Tags: symbols

1. Windows XP with Service Pack 3 x86 retail symbols, all languages (File size: 209 MB - Most customers want this package.)
2. Windows XP with Service Pack 3 x86 checked symbols, all languages (File size: 202 MB)

Quoted from [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/gg463028.aspx).

What's the difference between retail symbols and checked symbols?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In general, the difference between "retail" and "checked" is similar to a "release" versus "debug" build. Microsoft provides two different kernels, one compiled for regular use and one with extra debug information. The two different builds also have two different symbol tables.

Comment: @Greg Hewgill,Symbols are for debug,release versions don't have any debug info,right? If that's the case ,what's the retail symbol for?

Comment: I just checked the size of retail and checked symbols,their sizes are very close, 209 MB and 202 MB respectively.

Comment: Both the retail and checkec symbols are pdb files for debug.

Comment: The retail build still has symbols, they're the addresses of all the functions.

Comment: So both retail and checked have debug info,what's different?

Comment: The checked build does a lot more things like verification of API function parameters. Using a checked build of the kernel can help locate problems in applications under development. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff543450.aspx for more information.

Comment: But did you notice that the file size are very close?

Comment: Yes, you mentioned that. I don't know whether you can infer anything from file size alone.

Comment: From Microsoft site: If you are **debugging a special version of Windows** with extra debugging information, then you should download the symbols for the checked version.

Comment: The size of the files is roughly the same because there are just as many functions in both versions. Symbol-files serve to map source-files and line-numbers to memory offsets in the binary executable. The difference between a debug and release (or checked and retail) version is that the debug version has some extra instrumentation for setting breakpoints and stuff like that.

Comment: @gdb The only possible reason about the reduced size of checked symbol package is perhaps the checked build of the OS already incorporates some debugging symbols and so the size of the checked symbol package is lesser.

Answer (score 5):

If you are an IT or Computer Science student in college (or if you happen to have access to MSDN's e-Academy software), you will probably have access to the special debug/checked builds of Windows Vista/7. Some professionals in the software development and engineering industries may have installations of the special debug builds as well. Otherwise, whether you come across Home or Professional editions--even Enterprise and Business editions--it will most likely be the retail version. All of those versions will require the retail version of the debugging symbols. However, if you have a debug/checked build of Windows installed, you will need the checked debug symbols.

As Greg has explained, the debugging symbols are basically an address. As far as I understand, they're basically a proper name for a function or item in memory, so when a user is debugging a process or viewing a callstack, he or she will be able to see usable information instead of address offsets.

Greg answered this already as well, but I'll try to elaborate. The retail and debug builds of Windows need different versions of symbols because the operating system files are compiled differently to include more useful debugging information. This makes the addresses for the symbols move ever so slightly, so a different package is required to correctly identify everything in memory.

The one thing I'm confused by is why the checked symbol package is smaller. I would have figured it would be bigger. A guru might know the reason for that. Speaking of which, I'd like to make it clear that I'm no debugger. I'm just fascinated with the science behind it. Nonetheless, I hope this helped you out.

Good luck gdb.

Comment: The only possible reason about the reduced size of checked symbol package is perhaps the checked build of the OS already incorporates some debugging symbols and so the size of the checked symbol package is lesser.

Comment: Or possibly just compression differences :P

Answer (score 1):

For practical purposes, desription of both packages was given in microsoft article https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/download-symbols . For been precise,

**"Almost all customers require the symbols for the retail version. If you are debugging a special version of Windows with extra debugging information, then you should download the symbols for the checked version."**

In other words, most likely you need **retail** version.